# How to capture images continuously with AV Foundation?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to implement QRcode reader with AV Foundation. My plan is capturing images continuously, sending captured images to QRcode detector until a valid code is recognized. The detector needs `CGImageRef` or `UIImage` as input. My questiones are:

1. Which output should I use: `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` or `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`?
2. How to take images continuously each, for example, 500ms? How long the interval should be?

Answer (score 1):

`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` gives you the Uncompressed YUV frame which you can easily send to QRCode reader if it supports uncompressed inputs. Hence you will be avoiding decoding operation.

If `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is used you can set frame rate in `AVFormatDescription` and set that to `AVCaptureDevice`. Once you start the `AVCaptureSession` you receive frames continuously at the specified frame rate until you stop it. Typically you can set 5 fps and make sure that this operation is asynchronous and you preferably process QRCode in a different thread so that in between two frame capture events you process the QRCode decode operation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried, but could not find documentations on AVFormatDescription. And how to let AVCaptureVideoDataOutput produce Uncompressed YUV frame? I'm quite new to AV capture.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. Set the sampleBufferDelegate of AVCaptureDataOutput to whatever class (say x)you want to receive the sample buffer. Confirm class x to AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate protocol. Implement– captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: method of that protocol in class x. Add AVCaptureVideoDataOutput instance to AVCaptureSession. Then start the session. You will receive the callback with sample buffer.